# Unable to set ACL for user and groups in rootless containers

Tags: access-control-list, containers

i'm running a Debian container in rootless mode and can't set an acl for groups and users besides my own group and user (at least it seems so). I started a bash in a container ( `runc --root /var/slurm/run/ run --bundle ~/containers/test01/ test01`) and then:

```
touch test.txt
setfacl -m g:adm:r-x test.txt
```

This leads to `setfacl: test.txt: Invalid argument.`

The group 'adm' exists. No other groups of /etc/groups/ works but my primary group `setfacl -m u:root:r-x test.txt` works fine.

That's the current user:

```
(base) root@runc:/# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),65534(nogroup)
```

I first thought of Linux Caps and played around a bit, but I can't get it working. Capsh prints:

```
(base) root@runc:/# capsh --print
Current: cap_fowner,cap_kill,cap_net_bind_service,cap_sys_admin,cap_audit_write=ep
Bounding set =cap_fowner,cap_kill,cap_net_bind_service,cap_sys_admin,cap_audit_write
Ambient set =
Current IAB: !cap_chown,!cap_dac_override,!cap_dac_read_search,!cap_fsetid,!cap_setgid,!cap_setuid,!cap_setpcap,!cap_linux_immutable,!cap_net_broadcast,!cap_net_admin,!cap_net_raw,!cap_ipc_lock,!cap_ipc_owner,!cap_sys_module,!cap_sys_rawio,!cap_sys_chroot,!cap_sys_ptrace,!cap_sys_pacct,!cap_sys_boot,!cap_sys_nice,!cap_sys_resource,!cap_sys_time,!cap_sys_tty_config,!cap_mknod,!cap_lease,!cap_audit_control,!cap_setfcap,!cap_mac_override,!cap_mac_admin,!cap_syslog,!cap_wake_alarm,!cap_block_suspend,!cap_audit_read,!cap_perfmon,!cap_bpf,!cap_checkpoint_restore
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-ambient-raise: no (unlocked)
uid=0(root) euid=0(root)
gid=0(root)
groups=0(root),65534(nogroup),65534(nogroup),65534(nogroup),65534(nogroup)
Guessed mode: UNCERTAIN (0)
```

The same occurs of I want to set a acl for a *user* other than root.

Edit:

The hint regarding subgid might be helpful, at least it enhanced my understanding of user/group namespace mapping.
Inside the container it seams that I have the following mapping:

```
(base) root@runc:/# cat /proc/self/gid_map
         0       1000          1
```

Here I can see that the group inside the container (0=root) is mapped to group id 1000 on the host system, and this is the group id of the user that started the rootless container.
**But** there's a rang of 1, does this mean, this this single group can be mapped and can this be the cause why I can't `chgrp adm foo`?

Any hint is very appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would start with `man subgid`.

Comment: And use a simpler case: `touch foo; chgrp adm foo` : do you get the same EINVAL?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error: "chgrp: changing group of 'foo': Invalid argument".

Comment: acl are usually used when you have multiple users accessing to a filesystem, In a containers usually you have a single account, used to run the application, look like you want to use a container as a server .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. I need to add uidMappings und gidMappings to to config.json, basically

```
        {
            "containerID": 1,
            "hostID": 231072,
            "size": 65536
        }
```

I just had a mapping from the root user within the container (id: 0) to the user that launched the container on the host (id: 1002). After adding additional mappings, the inside-container users could be mapped to ids that are valid on the host, too.